# in grep -f, can I print what pattern caused the match instead of matched pattern?

Tags: linux, grep

In the command `grep -f input_pat.txt match_in.txt`, I am looking for a way where I print what pattern matched from `input_pat.txt` instead of the final matched string in `matched_in.txt`.

For example, `input_pat.txt` contains:

```
abc...blahblah
```

and `match_in.txt` has:

```
abcdefblahblah
```

I'd like to print `"abc...blahblah"` in the output.

Comment: I don't think there's anything like that. But the `--color` option of GNU grep may let you figure out which of the patterns was the one matched.

Comment: Thanks, I think what your suggestion is can also be achieved with -o?

Comment: Yes. Notice that `-o` is also an non-standard switch.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by invoking grep twice - a little costly but does the job
Let's assume that your pattern file is pat.txt and the file you wish to search is  data.txt.

```
paste <(grep -o -f pat.txt  data.txt ) <(grep -f pat.txt data.txt )
```

We use process substitution `<( ... )` so that `paste` treats the two output of the two commands as files. 
In the first command the `-o` option prints only the matched pattern
In the second command the complete matched line is printed.

Since the order is one-to-one the two outputs can be safely pasted side by side (assuming there are no changes to either the pattern file or the data file while the grep is being is performed)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question as asked. The question also says nothing about one-to-one. Each or any pattern could match more than once per line.

Comment: In my soluton every pattern would be printed along with its line. By "one-to-one" I meant match between the two greps

Comment: `grep -o` doesn't output the patterns but each non-empty matched string. If `pat.txt` contains `.` for instance, `grep -o -f pat.txt data.txt` will print each character in every line of `data.txt` one per line.

Answer (score 0):

If switching to extended regexps (like those of `grep -E`) is acceptable, you could use `awk` instead and do it like:

```
awk '
  !end_of_re_list {if (!(re[$0]++)) n++; next}
  {
    for (i in re)
      if ($0 ~ i) {
        print i
        delete re[i]
        if (--n == 0) exit
      }
  }' input_pat.txt end_of_re_list=1 match_in.txt
```